# Confusion on the definitions of product topology

Tags: general-topology, products

All the books I have read so far defined the product topology $\tau$ on the finite Cartesian product of spaces $(X_i, \tau_i)_{i \le n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by the topology generated by the basis
$$
B = \{\prod_{i \le n} U_i ~|~ \forall i \le n: U_i \in \tau_i\}
$$
(Is the generated topology called the box topology?)

But I recently encountered a weird definition on [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Product_Topology), where the topology is defined by using the canonical projection maps:
$$
\tau
=
\{ \pi_i^{-1}[U] ~|~ i \le n,~ U \in \tau_i\}
$$
to make the preimages of open subsets of each space also open in the product space.

But in my knowledge, the preimage of $U$ under $\pi_i : \prod_k X_k \to X_i$ is
$$
X_1 \times \cdots \times X_{i-1} \times U \times X_{i+1} \times \cdots \times X_n
$$
that looks like a cylinder.
I doubt this is even a topology because the intersection of any two preimages from different $i$'s does not belong to $\tau$.

The only way I can relate $\tau$ with a topology is taking it as a subbasis for the Cartesian product $\prod_k X_k$.

Is there something I am missing here? Is $\tau$ indeed a topology as in the ProofWiki definition?

Comment: on finite product, box topology and product topology coincides...

Comment: And, yes, the second definition is the general one, and yields a subbasis of the product topology. The point being that the product topology is the coarsest one that makes all projection continuous.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thank you for the comment. Then, isn't it wrong to say the set is a product topology?

Comment: The product topology is the topology with the fewest open sets that makes every projection continuous. In other words it's the category-theoretic product.

Comment: If you are referring to the ProofWiki definition (if not, please clarify), it looks correct to me. They define the product topology as the **initial topology**  in which those preimages are open - that is to say, the coarsest (set-theoretic smallest) topology in which those preimages are open.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Yes, I understood. But I am saying that we have to find the coarsest topology containing $\tau$, and $\tau$ itself in the post is not a topology.

Comment: As you correctly stated, it is a subbase for the product topology. A base will be provided, as usual, by the finite intersections of the members of the subbase.

Comment: ProofWiki does not claim that that collection is a topology.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I think I got it now. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a countable family of spaces $(X_i, \tau_i), i \in \Bbb N$ then the ProofWiki definition is a special case of the general product (for any number of spaces). There we consider all projections $\pi_i: X \to X_i$, where $X = \prod_{i \in \Bbb N} X_i$ (as a set), and define the product topology $\tau_p$ to be the *smallest* topology on $X$ such that all $\pi_i$ become continuous. Basic facts:

- Sets of the form $\pi_i^{-1}[U_i]$, where $i \in \Bbb N$ and $U_i \in \tau_i$, together form a *subbase* for $\tau_p$.
- It follows that the standard base (from that subbase) consists of all sets of the form $$\pi_{i_1}^{-1}[U_{i_1}] \cap \ldots \cap \pi_{i_m}^{-1}[U_{i_m}]$$ where $\{i_1, \ldots, i_m\} \subseteq \Bbb N$ is finite.
- That set thus looks like (for the $\Bbb N$_case): $$X_1 \times \ldots \times U_{i_1} \times \ldots \times U_{i_2} \times \ldots \times U_{i_m} \times X_{{i_m}+1} \times \ldots$$ where all intermediate factors (not equal to some $U_{i_j}$) just are all full spaces $X_j$ for the right indices. Quite messy notation, but that's what the intersection means: finitely many coordinates are constrained (in that the points $(p_n)_n$ in the product must have $p_{i_j} \in U_{i_j}$ for a finite set of indices and corresponding open sets) and the others are free to choose in the correct factor space.

But when the index set is $\Bbb N$ and we have such a finite set of indices, we can just take that finite set to be $\{1, \ldots, k\}$ for some finite $k$ and we can just take it to be of the easier form

$$U_1 \times U_2 \times \ldots U_k \times X_{k+1} \times X_{k+2} \times \ldots$$ provided we allow for $U_i = X_i$ sometimes; then we can make all basic open subsets in this shape (cilinder sets) and then we're back at the OP's form of basic open sets. The OP's form is just a spacial case of the ProofWiki form and all ProofWiki's forms can be written as the OP's type. So they define exactly the same base and the same topology, even though they may look different at first sight....

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer! 1) It seems you expanded the discussion to countably infinite-dimensional product spaces and stated that the Cartesian products of a finite collection of non-entire open sets form a subbasis. 2) And $\tau_p$ is the smallest one in the sense that we can generate a topology taking it as a subbasis. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @Hermis14 In *any* product the set of "boxes" $\prod_{i \in I} U_i$, where only at most finitely many $i$ are not $X_i$, is a basis for its topology. The subbasis are the ones where exactly *one* is not $X_i$, and these are of the form $\pi_i^{-1}[U_i]$. And finally the smallest topology containing a collection is precisely the topology that has that collection as a subbasis.